# How to set a shortcut command to go to a certain folder

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I want to create cmd shortcut like 'myrepo' which directs me to 'C:\Users\myuser\GitRepos\mygitrepo'

Example:

```
C:\>set myrepo=C:\Users\myuser\GitRepos\mygitrepo
C:\>cd myrepo
C:\Users\myuser\GitRepos\mygitrepo>
```

I tried setting up a variable and calling it back but it only last for the duration of the session. I am exploring if there are any solutions to that without adding stuff to SYSTEM ENVIRONMENTS variable.

Comment: What's wrong with the user environment variable. Plus you only need one line `cd  C:\Users\myuser\GitRepos\mygitrepo`

Comment: to reference a variable, use `%variable%`: `cd %myrepo%`

Comment: `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\GitRepos\mygitrepo"`

Comment: The problem with setting a variable through cmd is that it will last only for the current session. But I will try setting up user environment variable.